# Limit of the serie $ u_{n,k}=\frac{1}{ \left(1 + \frac{k b_n}{n} \right)^n }$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

- $k \geq 1, n \geq 2  $
- $(b_n)_{n \geq 2}$ strictly positive and converges to $l >0$
- $ u_{n,k}=\dfrac{1}{ \left(1 + \dfrac{k b_n}{n} \right)^n} $
- $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^{ \infty} u_{n,k}$
- $S_{n,p}=\sum_{k=1}^{ p} u_{n,k}$

We want to find the limit of $S_n$.

---

My attempt :

1. $n$ fixed, $\dfrac{ u_{n,k} }{ u_{n,k+1} } =\dfrac{  1+ \dfrac{k b_n}{n}  } { 1+ \dfrac{(k+1) b_n}{n}  } < 1$ so, with $n$ fixed, the serie $u_{k,n}$ converges.

$
\begin{align*}
x,u &>0\\
x &\geq \ln(1+x) \\
\dfrac{u}{n} &\geq  \ln (1+ \dfrac{u}{n}) \\
-u &\leq - n \ln ( 1 +\dfrac{u}{n} ) \\
e^{-u} &\leq ( 1 + \dfrac{u}{n}   )^{-n} \\
e^{-k b_n} &\leq ( 1 + \dfrac{k b_n}{n}   )^{-n} \\
\sum_{k=1}^{ +\infty} e^{-k b_n}  &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{ +\infty} ( 1 + \dfrac{k b_n}{n}   )^{-n} \\
\dfrac{e^{-b_n}}{ 1 -e^{-b_n}}  &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{ +\infty} ( 1 + \dfrac{k b_n}{n}   )^{-n} \\
\dfrac{1}{ e^{b_n}-1}  &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{ +\infty} ( 1 + \dfrac{k b_n}{n}   )^{-n} \\
\dfrac{1}{ e^{b_n}-1}  &\leq S_n\\
\end{align*}
$

2. $f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{ \left(1 + \dfrac{x b_n}{n} \right)^n } $ decreasing on  $ \mathbb{R}_+$,
   so $\forall j \leq 1$

\begin{align*}
f_n(j) &\leq \int_{j-1}^j f_n(x) dx \\
\sum_{j=1}^{r} f_n(j) &\leq \int_{0}^r f_n(x) dx \\
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_n(j) &\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx \\
S_n &\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx \\
\end{align*}

3.
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+ \infty} b_n f_n (x)dx &= \dfrac{n}{-n+1}  \left[  \left(1 + \dfrac{x b_n}{n}  \right) ^{-n+1}  \right]_{0} ^{+\infty}  \\
&= 1+ \dfrac{1}{n} \\
&\leq 2 \\
\end{align*}

4. $\exists \epsilon >0 ,  \exists N, \forall n,   l - \epsilon < u_n$ avec $ l - \epsilon >0$. Let $l- \epsilon =b$ , we obtain $0 \leq u_{k,n} \leq \dfrac{1}{  \left( 1+ \dfrac{kb}{n} \right)^n}$

\begin{align*}
h(x) &=\left( 1 + \dfrac{kb}{x}  \right)^{-x} \\
&= \exp \left ( -x \ln  \left( 1 + \dfrac{kb}{x}  \right) \right) \\
h'(x)&=\left[    -  \ln  \left( 1 + \dfrac{kb}{x}  \right) -x -   \dfrac{kb}{x^2}  \ln  \left( 1 + \dfrac{kb}{x}  \right)                  \right] h(x) \\
h'(x) &<0 \\
\end{align*}

$h$ decreasing $ 0 \leq u_{n,k} =h(n) \leq h(2)$

5. Let $v_k= \dfrac{1}{  \left( 1 + \dfrac{kb}{2}  \right)^2 }$ , the serie  $ [ v_k ]$ converges, like $ (n^{-2})_{n \geq 1}$

$ 
\begin{align*}
S_{n,p+r}- S_{n,p} &= \sum_{j=p}^{ j=p+r} u_{n,j} \\
 & \leq \sum_{j=p}^{ j=p+r} v_j  \\
&\underset{j \to \infty} \to 0 \\
\end{align*}
$

Criterium of Cauchy uniform, the bound doesn't not depend of $n$.

$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \lim_{p \rightarrow  \infty} S_{n,p} &= \lim_{p \rightarrow  \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} S_{n,p} \\
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
\left( 1+ \dfrac{z}{n} \right)^{-n} &\to e^{-z} \\
\left( 1+ \dfrac{k b_n}{n} \right)^{-n} &\to e^{-kl}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} u_{k,n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty}e^{-kl} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} u_{k,n} &= \dfrac{ e^{-l} } { 1- e^{-l}} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} u_{k,n} &= \dfrac{ 1} {e^{l} -1 } \\
\end {align*}
$

Comment: I think $S_n$ diverges for all $n$. It is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_(mathematics)

Comment: $b_n S_n \leq 2$, the serie converges and it depends on $l$.

Comment: I have fixed a typo in the definition of the serie.